# Find **one** projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm to find **one** standard matrix for projection using homogeneous coordinates onto the line $4x-2y=0$.

I did find a standard matrix for projection using the fact that:

$$A= \frac{1}{d_{1}^2 + d_{2}^2} \left( \begin{matrix} d_{1}^2 & d_1 d_2 \\ d_1 d_2 & d_{2}^2 \end{matrix} \right) $$

is the standard matrix for projection, where $d$ are direction vectors.

So I computed:

$$\frac{1}{1+m^2} \left( \begin{matrix} 1&m \\ m&m^2 \end{matrix} \right)$$

where $m$ is the slope of my line (2).

My projection matrix (standard matrix) was: $$ \left( \begin{matrix} 1/5 & 2/5 \\ 2/5 & 4/5 \end{matrix} \right)$$

And projecting $(3,1)$ I got $(1,2)$.

I'm not 100% sure that I'm doing it right but any way, I'm not sure what they mean by now finding **one** projection matrix and what are homogeneous coordinates? I am also asked to project the point $(3,1)$ again using this matrix.

Comment: If $(1,7/5)$ is supposed to be on the line $4x-2y$, then you've done something wrong because $4\cdot 1 - 2\cdot\frac{7}{5}\ne 0$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what I've found but I don't think it's a point on the line

Comment: Nevermind, I made an error, it's supposed to go to $(1,2)$

Comment: I tried clarifying my question

Comment: Your projection matrix looks correct now. And if you projection the point $(1,2)$ again, what do you think will happen (based on the fact that $(1,2)$ is already on the line)? I'm also not sure about what your Instructor means by homogenous coordinates.